# Spring + JSF2 + JSR 303 bean validation

Tags: java, spring, primefaces, bean-validation, jsf-2.2

I'm using Spring 3.2.2 with Primefaces 4.0 and Hibernate 4.2. I have JSR 303 validation annotations on my entities, and I have spring configured to validate them at the service layer - that much works fine.

But I'd like JSF validation to kick in before calling the service but it doesn't. All the research I've done says I just have to add a validator to the classpath and JSF2 will automatically apply.

I've added the suggested jars to my classpath:

```
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.primefaces.extensions:primefaces-extensions:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
```

Full dependency tree can be seen at https://gist.github.com/prule/7411171

My validated object and managed bean:

```
public class ValidatedObject {
    @NotEmpty
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ValidatedController {
    private ValidatedObject object = new ValidatedObject();

    public ValidatedObject getObject() {
        return object;
    }


    public void onSave() {
        System.out.println("saving");
    }
}
```

Facelets page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

    <h:body>
        <h:form >
            <p:messages />
            <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{validatedController.object.name}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{validatedController.onSave}" ajax="false"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Spring config contains:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>
```

All the questions and answers I've found are basic JSF2 (without spring) or spring-web based. Have I got something missing or incorrect with my spring/jsf integration?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW I am using Tomcat 7, JDK 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Spring is not compatible (yet) with JEE7/JSF2.2 Bean validation. Either wait for a compatible set or use a JEE7 compatible DI framework like JBoss WELD that is shipped by default with GF4.

Comment: Heh, I was thinking there would be an answer like that. Thanks.

Comment: Here it is...
Bean valudation 1.1 should be supported from Spring 4

"Support for key Java EE 7 technologies:
including JMS 2.0, JPA 2.1, `Bean Validation 1.1`, Servlet 3.1, and JCache"

Comment: Spring 3.2 does support JSR303 though, but is it just not supported when using with JSF? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validation-beanvalidation-overview

Comment: JSF 2.2 is part of JEE7 where bean validation is now JSR349. @See https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates